# distinct values for column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, postgresql-9.2

I have the following table with below data

```
id    description
 1    a,b,a
```

I need a PostgreSQL script that give me below output

```
id   description
1    a,b
```

This what I have tried so far.

```
create temporary table test
(
  id integer,
  description text
);

insert into test
select 1,'a,b,a';

select id,string_agg(distinct description, ',') as description
from test
group by id;
```

Comment: Please clarify that. Can you at least provide `CRATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for an example? Where does XML come in?

Answer (score 3):

The best solution for your problem is to normalize your data model and don't store multiple, comma separated values in a single column.

But you can achieve what you want using a combination of unnest and aggregation:

```
select id, string_agg(distinct c, ',' order by c)
from the_table, unnest(string_to_array(description, ',')) as t(c)
group by id;
```

With the outdated (and unsupported) version 9.2 you need to use a derived table:

```
select id, string_agg(distinct c, ',' order by c) as description
from (
  select id, unnest(string_to_array(description, ',')) as c
  from the_table
) t
group by id;
```

Online example (for 9.6): http://rextester.com/LEE56363

Comment: you missed the unnest

Comment: I'm getting below error

ERROR:  function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level
LINE 11: from test, unnest(string_to_array(description,',')) as t(c)

Comment: While executing this query
create temporary table test
(
id integer,
description text
);

insert into test
select 1,'a,b,a';

select id, string_agg(distinct c, ',' order by c)
from test, unnest(string_to_array(description,',')) as t(c)
group by id;

Comment: @KAN: I forgot that your outdated Postgres version does not support that. See my edit.